# ruby class declaration question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in ruby you can have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :require_login
end
```

i just wonder what is before_filter? it's a method from ActionController::Base?

and what will happen if i create an object of ApplicationController? The before_filter method will be run?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `before_filter` is a method on ActionController::Base.  Anything specified in `before_filter` will run before the action(s) being called.

API Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000316

EDIT:

When you write directly into a class, that code is executed when the class is loaded into the interpreter.

Typing this into IRB:

```
>> class Hello
>> p "hello"
>> end
"hello"
```

so in the case you mentioned ruby sees the `before_filter` method and it tries to find it.  It starts looking in its class, then it goes into the parent and the parent's parent, and so on until it gets to `Object`.  In this case, it will go up to the ActionController::Base class and look for the `before_filter` and then up the chain to class, module and object.

```
>> ActionController::Base.class
=> Class
>> ActionController::Base.class.superclass
=> Module
>> ActionController::Base.class.superclass.superclass
=> Object
>> ActionController::Base.class.superclass.superclass.superclass
```

If you are up for reading, I highly recommend [MetaProgramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby), it does a much better job of explaining the object model than I can.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i was more wondering about the ruby programming. what does it mean when you type a method name in the open in a class?

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a method inside a class definition, you are actually doing this:

```
class ApplicationController
  self.before_filter
end
```

when self is the class object itself (for instance, try `puts self` in the class definition)

For example, a poor man way of defining a filter would be

```
class Filterable

    @@filters = []

    def self.before_filter(method_name)
      @@filters << method_name
    end

    def self.filters
      @@filters
    end

    def some_important_method
      self.class.filters.each do |method_name|
        # Halt execution if the return value of one of them is false or nil
        return unless self.send(method_name)
      end
      puts "I'm in some important method"
      # Continue with method execution
    end

end

class SomeClass < Filterable

  before_filter :first_filter
  before_filter :second_filter

  attr_accessor :x

  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def first_filter
    puts "I'm in first filter"
    true
  end

  def second_filter
    puts "I'm in second filter"
    @x > 5
  end

end
```

And you can test it

```
SomeClass.new(8).some_important_method
# => I'm in first filter
#    I'm in second filter
#    I'm in some important method

SomeClass.new(3).some_important_method
# => I'm in first filter
#    I'm in second filter
```

Hope it is clarifying

Answer (score 2):

It is important to know that on ruby the code inside a class declaration isn't "special".

It's just regular code. You are not limited to defining methods and class variables - your code there can do pretty much anything.

You can, for example, do stuff like this:

```
class MyClass
  print "wow"
end
```

After the end, this prints "wow" and returns nil.

I'll say that again: You can do include much anything you want inside a class definition. *Including invoking methods that modify the class itself*.

That is exactly what `before_filter` does. It modifies the class, in a way that "before any method on this class is invoked, `require_login` must be automatically called".

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) explains it pretty well.  Basically Ruby is allowing syntactic "sugar" allowing you to define a block of ruby code that will run at a specific time.  In the `before_filter` case it will be run before any action methods.